# $s(t) = |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t} u_{n}(x) dx|^{2}$ is a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{u_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal subset of $L^{2}[0,1]$. Prove that the function $$s(t) =\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t} u_{n}(x) dx\right|^{2}$$

is a restriction of a polynomial by determinating such polynomial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\| \sum u_n\|$ does not make sense. The series does not converge in the norm.  Is it possible that the absolute value sign is in the wrong place in the question?

Comment: True,  the bound I put it is useless. This question is from a test of mine. I checked and the question is exactly this. @KaviRamaMurthy